# XML not loading

Tags: android, xml

```
   package table.periodic;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Solu extends ListActivity {

    String[] formulas={ "Formulas", "Al<sup><small>2</small></sup>(SO<sup><small>4</small></sup>)<sup><small>3</small></sup>"

    };

    String[] C0s={ "0°C", "31.2"

    };

    String[] C20s={ "20°C", "36.4"

    };

    String[] C60s={ "60°C", "59.2"

    };

    String[] C100s={ "100°C", "89.0"

    };

    public static final int ONE_ID = Menu.FIRST+1;
    public static final int TWO_ID = Menu.FIRST+2;
    public static final int THREE_ID = Menu.FIRST+3;
    public static final int FOUR_ID = Menu.FIRST+4;

    public void OnCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());

    }

    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object>{
        IconicAdapter(){

            super(Solu.this, R.layout.row);

        }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView formula=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.formula);
        TextView C0=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.C0);
        TextView C20=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.C20);
        TextView C60=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.C60);
        TextView C100=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.C100);

        formula.setText(formulas[position]);
        C0.setText(C0s[position]);
        C20.setText(C20s[position]);
        C60.setText(C60s[position]);
        C100.setText(C100s[position]);

        return(row);

        }

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){


    }

     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
            populateMenu(menu);
        }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            populateMenu(menu);

            return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));

        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            return(applyMenuChoice(item)||
                    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));

        }
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            return(applyMenuChoice(item)||
                    super.onContextItemSelected(item));
        }
        private void populateMenu(Menu menu){
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, ONE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Help");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, TWO_ID, Menu.NONE, "Home");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, THREE_ID, Menu.NONE, "List");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, FOUR_ID, Menu.NONE, "Table");
        }

        private boolean applyMenuChoice(MenuItem item){
            switch (item.getItemId()){

            case ONE_ID:

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Help")
                .setMessage("Solubilities are given in grams of solute that can be dissolved in 100 g of water at the temperature (°C) indicated.")
                .setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin){

                    }
                })
                .show();

                return(true);

            case TWO_ID:

                Intent table = new Intent(this, table.class);
                startActivity(table);
                finish();
                return(true);

            case THREE_ID:

                Intent list = new Intent(this, List.class);
                startActivity(list);
                finish();
                return(true);

            case FOUR_ID:
                Intent Classic = new Intent(this, Classic.class);
                startActivity(Classic);
                finish();
                return(true);

            }
            return false;
        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

XML LIST

XML ROW

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15dp" android:id="@+id/formula" android:text="form" android:layout_width="75dp"></TextView>
  <TextView android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="0C" android:id="@+id/C0" android:layout_width="30dp"></TextView>
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15dp" android:id="@+id/C20" android:text="20C" android:layout_width="35dp"></TextView>
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15dp" android:id="@+id/C60" android:text="60C" android:layout_width="35dp"></TextView>
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15dp" android:id="@+id/C100" android:text="60C" android:layout_width="35dp"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thats the basic layout that the XML follows except I have around 400+ TextViews

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of putting the XML in a SO comment, but the XML you've pasted isn't well formed. You have a semicolon after the `xmlns:android` and you're missing a `</LinearLayout>` closing tag at the end.

Comment: @Joshua: suggest you narrow your question down to contain only the relevant code. There's far too much irrelevant code for an answerer to wade through. Also consider posting it on PasteBin.

Comment: @p.campbell I've cleaned up the code a bit. Hopefully that helps. Let me know if it needs more cleanup

Comment: Why do you have an XML layout with 400+ TextViews?  Use a ListView.  That is going to be incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @Mayra I would use a ListView if I knew how to have 4 columns and was able to format it in HTML. Like my first whole column needs HTML and the last column needs some so that I can superscript. If you can direct me to where I can figure out how to do that then great. Otherwise I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an arbitrary layout to be used in the ListView adapter, like [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), or [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) so it can have 4 columns and whatever you want inside.

The only challenge is that you would need to set some explicit sizing (i.e. percent of width view `layout_weight`) for the columns, not make it based on the input.

You can also look at using a `TableLayout`, however it doesn't have support for object reuse like `ListView` does, so it might also have problems handling 400 rows on some phones.

Comment: Ok. I think there is another problem here. I don't know whats wrong here but I've tried calling a different layout and loading up a list view like you suggest but I'm not getting anything. I can still get to the menu but for some reason I've got no layout.

Comment: Show us the simplest layout that isn't working, along with any logcat messages around the time of loading.

Comment: My simplest layout that I'm trying is literally just a relative layout. I'll update the code up top to reflect what I have now so you can see what I've got.

Comment: Well you aren't going to see anything if you only have a relative layout.. you need something in the relative layout.

Comment: Oh, you are extending ListActivity.. why are you supplying a layout at all then?  It has a ListView already by default. If you want to do something special, just follow the basic ListActivity documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html  You at least need a ListView.

Comment: I changed it to a relative layout after my list I use in another activity didn't load. It might be because I have it loading the list differently so I'll try loading it the same tomorrow. The weird thing is that it doesn't load my background image though.

Comment: updated. Its still not loading. Is my code correct for filling 4 text views in each row like I'm trying to do? Or no? And any idea why I cant get this XML to load?

Comment: No, what you are doing does not make any sense. A different instance of the Row item layout is going to be created for each row, why are you holding on to some arbitrary instance of it in onCreate? You are setting the text of a text view in onListItemClick?  What you are trying to do is not complicated, there are hundreds of examples of using a simple ArrayAdapter with a custom row layout around.  For example: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/  I think you need to sepdn a little bit of time reading through the documentation.

Comment: updated. From what I have found this SHOULD work. But I'm still not getting anything to load but the menu.